# How can I create a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a game for class and I have decided to include an admin area where settings may be modified. Currently this is how I have established a database connection:

db_config.php:

```
<?php
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
defined('DB_USER') ? null : define('DB_USER', 'root');
defined('DB_PASS') ? null : define('DB_PASS', 'root');
defined('DB_NAME') ? null : define('DB_NAME', 'game');
?>
```

database.php:

```
<?php
require_once('db_config.php');

class DatabaseConnect {        
    public function __construct($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
        if (!@$this->Connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name)) {
            echo 'Connection failed.';
        } else if ($this->Connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name)){
        }
    }

    public function Connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
if (!mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
       }
    }
}

$connection =  new DatabaseConnect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

?>
```

Up to this point I have used `mysql_real_escape_string` in my queries and I know that I shouldn't be manually escaping. I am still learning PHP so some things take me a while to grasp. I have had a look at the php.net prepared statement manual but I am not sure whether I need to change the way I have connected to the database.

So basically what I am asking is if I had this query (or any query for that matter):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Process the form

  $id = $current_page["id"];
  $menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
  $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
  $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];
  $content = mysql_prep($_POST["content"]);

  // validations
  $required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible", "content");
  validate_presences($required_fields);

  $fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 30);
  validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

  if (empty($errors)) {

    // Perform Update

    $query  = "UPDATE pages SET ";
    $query .= "menu_name = '{$menu_name}', ";
    $query .= "position = {$position}, ";
    $query .= "visible = {$visible}, ";
    $query .= "content = '{$content}' ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
      // Success
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Page updated.";
      redirect_to("manage_content.php?page={$id}");
    } else {
      // Failure
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Page update failed.";
    }

  }
} else {
  // This is probably a GET request

} // end: if (isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```

How would it be changed into a prepared statement?

Comment: Here's [an example](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). By the way, with your `$query` variable, you don't need to repeatedly concatenate to create your string - just start with `$query = "` then write your query over many lines, and finish with the quote and a semi-colon. The database engine doesn't mind the extra tabs/spaces/new-lines at all, and the result is _much_ more readable.

Comment: (Btw, minor observation: I've noticed that all of your questions have a `...` ellipsis at the end of the title. This is unnecessary, and is likely to create edit work as wording is tweaked over time.)

Comment: Remember to search for, and read tutorials/references, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you create a prepared statement.

```
 $query = "UPDATE pages SET menu_name=?, position = ?,
 visible=?, content=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";

 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
 $result = false;
 if($stmt){
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "ssdsd", $menu_name,
     $position, $visible, $content,$id );

     $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

 }

 if($result){
     //Successful   
 }
 else{
    //Unsuccessful
 }
```

I made some assumptions regarding the type of the fields in the database but the notation is in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` , 's' stands for string and 'd' stands for integer.

Comment: Correct, you can also use a shortcut to bind multiple params on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

For the SQL portion, try this >>

```
$records_found = 0;
$record = false;
$cn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $data);

$query  = "UPDATE pages SET menu_name=?, position=?, visible=?, content=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1"
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $menu_name);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $position);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $visible);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $content);
$stmt->bind_param("d", $id);

$result = $stmt->execute();
if($result) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($records_found == 1) {
                break;
            }
            $record = $row;
            $records_found++;
       }
       mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}
mysqli_close($cn);

// Output the record found if any
if($record) {
    var_export($record);
} else {
    echo 'No records found';
}
```

Also, read the docs on it here >> [mysqli.prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) << as there are some really good examples.

**NOTE:  The above solution provides complete code from connecting to the db, to closing the connection and freeing the memory consumed, with a condition block after to allow you to work with the resulting row if any found. Basically, all trapping is complete aside from  `or die(mysqli_error($cn));` stuff.

Comment: Actually `$stmt->execute` just returns a boolean. So doing `$result->fetch_assoc()` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: my bad... skipped a line... hahaha... thank you :) -- editing now

Comment: Testing for success/failure in `execute` is still a good idea, though!

Comment: corrected....  sorry about the confusion.  changed `$result = $stmt->execute();` to `$stmt->execute();` and added `$result = $stmt->get_result();`

Comment: @halfer - I know, but lazy  :)  OP's question was more on the how to do it, not so much error control.  I can update with error control as well, but stuff starts to get messy :)

Comment: Of course. In situations where you would normally put in more code, you can always add a note into the question to explain what the extra code would do.

Comment: Agreed.  I updated the code so it would break on first record found, then free the result and allow for database to be closed. Also added some checks for resulting data (allows future viewers of this article to simply remove the break to enter code in the while{} loop, while providing a 1 row solution for the OP as their original code appears to do.